# HTML Webpack Plugin one file injection in multiple pages

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I was wondering if you guys could help me out with the HTMLwebpack plugin. 
I am quite a newbie to Webpack 4 and the HTMLwebpack plugin and I can't seem to get my head around this.

My idea was to use the plugin for templating the navigation on multiple pages.

One navigation.html file injected into the body of multiple pages. ( index.html and about.html etc. )

I've read the manual on GitHub and all kinds of articles related to the HTMLwebpack plugin in vain.

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

Soo here I am.

( I'm looking for someone who can explain or give a nudge in the right direction. Not a production ready code. )

I know the code I've got so far ain't much. This is due to the fact that I can't get my head around it.

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'about.html',
        template: 'pages/about.html'
    })
```

With kind regards,

Rick van der Straeten.

Comment: do you still need help? i solved it

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it ! I already solved it myself by using a `<%= require('html-loader!./components/meta.html') %>` inside each page but would love to see your solution !